# Inconsistency between local trained and Dataproc trained Spark ML model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am upgrading Spark from version 2.3.1 to 2.4.5. I am retraining a model with Spark 2.4.5 on Google Cloud Platform's Dataproc using Dataproc image 1.4.27-debian9. When I load the model produced by the Dataproc on my local machine using Spark 2.4.5 to validate the model. Unfortunately, I am getting the following exception:

```
20/05/27 08:36:35 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/.../target/classes/model.ml/stages/1_gbtc_961a6ef213b2/metadata/part-00000:0+657
20/05/27 08:36:35 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/.../target/classes/model.ml/stages/1_gbtc_961a6ef213b2/metadata/part-00000:0+657
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gbtc_961a6ef213b2 parameter impurity given invalid value variance.
```

The code to load the model is pretty simple:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel

object ModelLoad {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val modelInputPath = getClass.getResource("/model.ml").getPath
    val model = PipelineModel.load(modelInputPath)
  }
}
```

I followed the stack trace to inspect the `1_gbtc_961a6ef213b2/metadata/part-00000` model metadata file and found the following:

```
{
    "class": "org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassificationModel",
    "timestamp": 1590593177604,
    "sparkVersion": "2.4.5",
    "uid": "gbtc_961a6ef213b2",
    "paramMap": {
        "maxIter": 50
    },
    "defaultParamMap": {
        ...
        "impurity": "variance",
        ...
    },
    "numFeatures": 1,
    "numTrees": 50
}
```

The impurity is set to `variance` but my local spark 2.4.5 expects it to be `gini`. For sanity check, I retrained the model on my local spark 2.4.5. The `impurity` in model metadata file is set to `gini`.

So, I checked the spark 2.4.5 [setImpurity method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/GBTClassifier.html#setImpurity-java.lang.String-) in GBT Javadoc. It says `The impurity setting is ignored for GBT models. Individual trees are built using impurity "Variance."`. The spark 2.4.5 used by Dataproc seems to be consistent with the Apache Spark documentation. But, the Spark 2.4.5 that I use from Maven Central sets the `impurity` value to `gini`.

Does anyone know why is there such inconsistency between the Spark 2.4.5 in Dataproc and Maven Central?

I created a simple training code to reproduce the result locally:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object SimpleModelTraining {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val currentRelativePath = Paths.get("")
    val save_file_location = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath.toString

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark-test")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (0, 0),
      (1, 0),
      (1, 0),
      (0, 1),
      (0, 1),
      (0, 1),
      (0, 2),
      (0, 2),
      (0, 2),
      (0, 3),
      (0, 3),
      (0, 3),
      (1, 4),
      (1, 4),
      (1, 4)
    )).toDF("label", "category")

    val pipeline: Pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
      new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("category")).setOutputCol("features"),
      new GBTClassifier().setMaxIter(30)
    ))

    val pipelineModel: PipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
    pipelineModel.write.overwrite().save(s"$save_file_location/test_model.ml")
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark in Dataproc [back-ported](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#January_22_2019) a fix for [SPARK-25959](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25959) that can cause this inconsistency between your local-trained and Dataproc-trained ML models.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Do you know if we we use `variance` as loss function for GBTClassifier? It makes more sense to me to use `gini` for classification problem.